# Transparent marker without line inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzmark

In the plot below, I need to have transparent markers without the line passing through them. 
For instance, the triangles are transparent but have a line inside, while the circles are white but not transparent, so when they overlap with other markers I can't see the ones behind (e.g., the 4th red circle covers the blue + behind it).
How can I do this? I tried playing with `fill` and `opacity`, but none seems to work.

Here is the MWE source code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[%
ymin = -430,
ymax = -120,
line width = 1.5pt,
mark size = 4pt,
mark repeat = {2},
]

\addplot [color=blue, mark=+, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.957480807357\\
25  -407.963189641911\\
50  -348.341258904901\\
75  -300.95497457745\\
100 -258.298880770257\\
125 -243.890778388889\\
150 -226.421548850128\\
175 -215.832112386973\\
200 -208.517635426508\\
225 -199.096498330167\\
250 -189.692967894992\\
275 -186.753526449191\\
300 -183.497159414706\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=triangle, mark options={solid, blue, fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -397.39812645437\\
50  -354.929271612088\\
75  -295.09171831629\\
100 -249.262040196353\\
125 -218.243641560284\\
150 -197.947382605722\\
175 -189.906388849135\\
200 -180.230493968517\\
225 -176.304549666994\\
250 -175.748222868004\\
275 -173.241346781042\\
300 -171.599255498579\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=*, mark options={solid, blue, fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.957480807357\\
25  -378.795179413002\\
50  -304.921612885841\\
75  -256.604962585425\\
100 -214.004226470603\\
125 -200.756093258793\\
150 -178.52719562163\\
175 -171.100579318826\\
200 -168.623121164359\\
225 -162.97515948792\\
250 -159.712406558919\\
275 -158.41049116843\\
300 -154.723114522471\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=x, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -390.474896185393\\
50  -291.096856168457\\
75  -230.010617278154\\
100 -191.261312838266\\
125 -180.306609644372\\
150 -178.845379658163\\
175 -175.00445053184\\
200 -169.001928454372\\
225 -158.091329556207\\
250 -157.357412473193\\
275 -151.358012141298\\
300 -147.389801314761\\
};


\addplot [color=red, mark=+, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, red}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.957480807357\\
25  -414.946593981509\\
50  -359.981615335536\\
75  -298.093357705063\\
100 -259.317637521473\\
125 -234.620802887995\\
150 -219.964042527991\\
175 -193.897369886823\\
200 -187.112205665699\\
225 -185.340947104539\\
250 -183.150547448457\\
275 -175.778921819035\\
300 -174.648426114704\\
};


\addplot [color=red, mark=triangle, mark options={solid, red, fill=white, fill opacity=0}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -401.973519707451\\
50  -358.483658886226\\
75  -319.048621130437\\
100 -279.751537017567\\
125 -245.242260009398\\
150 -229.580752059355\\
175 -216.142874177003\\
200 -199.342475438751\\
225 -189.604601725526\\
250 -183.539205050181\\
275 -179.434918964193\\
300 -173.547274004663\\
};


\addplot [color=red, mark=*, mark options={solid, red, fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.501437134907\\
25  -372.559640943181\\
50  -308.209122258859\\
75  -273.406549290234\\
100 -238.771617912851\\
125 -229.104604465375\\
150 -221.052548304111\\
175 -213.010502464088\\
200 -199.973941023526\\
225 -197.974334957991\\
250 -198.191604035715\\
275 -196.993961931376\\
300 -196.945082195301\\
};


\addplot [color=red, mark=x, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, red}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -389.032852432164\\
50  -309.929903134395\\
75  -245.478400959056\\
100 -227.0428164581\\
125 -206.155626802297\\
150 -204.108240939745\\
175 -195.316558439083\\
200 -192.070716289052\\
225 -188.600255620281\\
250 -186.914288571696\\
275 -185.942141280223\\
300 -187.401409980353\\
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess to make this happen in general, you need to make the plot marks nodes such that Ti*k*Z can use `\pgfpointshapeborder` (see p. 1031 of the pgfmanual) internally to stop the plot at the boundary. AFAIK this is not possible for plain plot marks. This answer comes thus with a new style `spare node marks` to which you can pass a plot mark shape. It (ab)uses `show path construction` to draw the segments. In its present form, it is limited to straight lines, but one can make it work for curves, too. In your code, I replaced

```
\addplot [color=red, mark=triangle, mark options={solid, red,fill=white, fill opacity=0}]
```

by

```
\addplot [color=red,spare node marks={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=2pt}]
```

and the result is

[image]

As you can see, the blue line does not get wiped out inside the triangles, nor do the red plot lines run through the plot marks. The answer has also a `spare marks` style (my first attempt), which however suffers from the lack of suitable `\pgfpointshapeborder` coordinates.

Full MWE (I commented out the other red paths in order to avoid confusion):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{spare marks/.style={decorate,decoration={show path construction,
lineto code={\draw (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) node[inner sep=0pt] (aux0)
{\pgfuseplotmark{#1}}
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) node[inner sep=0pt] (aux1) {\pgfuseplotmark{#1}};
\draw (aux0) -- (aux1); }}},
spare node marks/.style={decorate,decoration={show path construction,
lineto code={\draw (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) node[inner sep=0pt,draw,#1] (aux0)
{} (\tikzinputsegmentlast) node[inner sep=0pt,draw,#1] (aux1) {};
\draw (aux0) -- (aux1); }}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]


\begin{axis}[%
ymin = -430,
ymax = -120,
line width = 1.5pt,
mark size = 4pt,
mark repeat = {2},
]

\addplot [color=blue, mark=+, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.957480807357\\
25  -407.963189641911\\
50  -348.341258904901\\
75  -300.95497457745\\
100 -258.298880770257\\
125 -243.890778388889\\
150 -226.421548850128\\
175 -215.832112386973\\
200 -208.517635426508\\
225 -199.096498330167\\
250 -189.692967894992\\
275 -186.753526449191\\
300 -183.497159414706\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=triangle, mark options={solid, blue, fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -397.39812645437\\
50  -354.929271612088\\
75  -295.09171831629\\
100 -249.262040196353\\
125 -218.243641560284\\
150 -197.947382605722\\
175 -189.906388849135\\
200 -180.230493968517\\
225 -176.304549666994\\
250 -175.748222868004\\
275 -173.241346781042\\
300 -171.599255498579\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=*, mark options={solid, blue, fill=white}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -472.957480807357\\
25  -378.795179413002\\
50  -304.921612885841\\
75  -256.604962585425\\
100 -214.004226470603\\
125 -200.756093258793\\
150 -178.52719562163\\
175 -171.100579318826\\
200 -168.623121164359\\
225 -162.97515948792\\
250 -159.712406558919\\
275 -158.41049116843\\
300 -154.723114522471\\
};


\addplot [color=blue, mark=x, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -390.474896185393\\
50  -291.096856168457\\
75  -230.010617278154\\
100 -191.261312838266\\
125 -180.306609644372\\
150 -178.845379658163\\
175 -175.00445053184\\
200 -169.001928454372\\
225 -158.091329556207\\
250 -157.357412473193\\
275 -151.358012141298\\
300 -147.389801314761\\
};


% \addplot [color=red, mark=+, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, red}]
% table[row sep=crcr]{%
% 1   -472.957480807357\\
% 25  -414.946593981509\\
% 50  -359.981615335536\\
% 75  -298.093357705063\\
% 100 -259.317637521473\\
% 125 -234.620802887995\\
% 150 -219.964042527991\\
% 175 -193.897369886823\\
% 200 -187.112205665699\\
% 225 -185.340947104539\\
% 250 -183.150547448457\\
% 275 -175.778921819035\\
% 300 -174.648426114704\\
% };
% 

%\addplot [color=red, mark=triangle, mark options={solid, red, fill=white, fill opacity=0}]
\addplot [color=red,spare node marks={regular polygon,regular polygon
sides=3,inner sep=2pt}]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -473.176111750593\\
25  -401.973519707451\\
50  -358.483658886226\\
75  -319.048621130437\\
100 -279.751537017567\\
125 -245.242260009398\\
150 -229.580752059355\\
175 -216.142874177003\\
200 -199.342475438751\\
225 -189.604601725526\\
250 -183.539205050181\\
275 -179.434918964193\\
300 -173.547274004663\\
};


% \addplot [color=red, mark=*, mark options={solid, red, fill=white}]
% table[row sep=crcr]{%
% 1   -472.501437134907\\
% 25  -372.559640943181\\
% 50  -308.209122258859\\
% 75  -273.406549290234\\
% 100 -238.771617912851\\
% 125 -229.104604465375\\
% 150 -221.052548304111\\
% 175 -213.010502464088\\
% 200 -199.973941023526\\
% 225 -197.974334957991\\
% 250 -198.191604035715\\
% 275 -196.993961931376\\
% 300 -196.945082195301\\
% };
% 
% 
% \addplot [color=red, mark=x, mark size=6pt, mark options={solid, red}]
% table[row sep=crcr]{%
% 1   -473.176111750593\\
% 25  -389.032852432164\\
% 50  -309.929903134395\\
% 75  -245.478400959056\\
% 100 -227.0428164581\\
% 125 -206.155626802297\\
% 150 -204.108240939745\\
% 175 -195.316558439083\\
% 200 -192.070716289052\\
% 225 -188.600255620281\\
% 250 -186.914288571696\\
% 275 -185.942141280223\\
% 300 -187.401409980353\\
% };


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Simon You're welcome. I can be simplified, depending on your real life requirements, and extended to curves and closed paths (see p. 583 where `curveto code` and `lineto code` are explained), and one may add a counter such that each node is drawn once etc. Please let me know if you have any such  "feature requests".